# Is the Metric Space Condition Necessary for $f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)}$ in Continuous Mappings?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I am working through Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" and came across Problem 2 on page 98, which states that if $f$ is a continuous mapping between metric spaces $X, Y$, then for any subset $E \subset X$, the image of the closure of $E$ under $f$ is contained in the closure of the image of $E$, i.e.,
$$ f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)}.$$

#### My Solution:

Suppose $\ell \in \overline{E}$, then we can choose a sequence of points $\{p_n\}$ from $E$ converging to $\ell$. Since $f$ is continuous, we will have
$$ f(p_n)\to f(\ell),$$
which just says $f(\ell)$ is inside the closure of $f(E)$, as desired.

I also noted that the interval $[1,\infty]$ is mapped by $\frac{1}{x}$ to $(0,1]$, which is not a closed subset, so $f(\overline{E})$ might be a proper subset of $\overline{f(E)}$.

#### My Question:

My proof relies on the properties of metric spaces, but I wonder if the condition that both $X, Y$ are metric spaces is necessary for this result. Is it possible to provide a proof without using metrics, or are there counterexamples where this property does not hold without the metric space condition? I would appreciate any insights or references that can help me understand this concept more deeply.

Answer (score 4):

True in  topological spaces. The proof is identical, except that you use nets instead of sequences. Characterization of continuity and closure using nets are available here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/General_Topology/Nets

It is also possible to prove this without using nets:

Let $x \in \overline E $. Let $y=f(x)$ and let $V$ be an open set containing $y$. Then $U=f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set containing $x$. Hence, $U \cap E\neq \emptyset$. If $z\in U\cap E$ then $f(z) \in f(E)\cap V$. Since every neighborhood of $y$ contains points of $f(E)$ it follows that $y \in \overline {f(E)}$.

Comment: crystal clear, txs.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the properties of the direct/inverse images.$\newcommand\l{\left(}\newcommand\r{\right)}$
$$\begin{align*}
E \subseteq f^{-1} \l f \l E \r \r &\subseteq f^{-1}\l \overline{f(E)} \r \\
\overline E &\subseteq f^{-1} \l \overline{f(E)} \r \text{ closed} \\
f\l \overline E\r \subseteq f\l f^{-1}\l \overline{f(E)}\r \r &\subseteq \overline{f(E)}
\end{align*}$$
It's also good to know that this is a characterization of continuity. Because if $f$ has this property, then for $F \subseteq Y$ closed:
$$f\l \overline{f^{-1}(F)}\r \subseteq \overline{f\l f^{-1}(F)\r} \subseteq \overline F = F.$$
Thus $$\overline{f^{-1}(F)} \subseteq f^{-1}\l f \l \overline{f^{-1}(F)}\r \r \subseteq f^{-1}(F)$$
And so $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed.